# Undo wordpress chmod?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

firstly im new to ubuntu and I did something im not sure of. I was trying to chmod  wordpress folder because it was having problem not having permission to do anything. (Already installed xampp)

Anyway after I did this bellow, I'm having issues with my desktop shortcuts being untrusted. I'm afraid it will mess up my whole system. How do I undo the things I've done?

I entered these commands in terminal:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R * 
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

All these commands are path-relative. That is to say, what they alter changes depending on what directory you're currently in. I suspect the instructions intended for you to be in your Wordpress directory *before* you ran this but that you fired these off before changing directory...

So if my suspicions are correct, you've changed the permissions on your home directory. That's pretty bad. You can check this with `ls -l` (while in your homedir).

Putting it right isn't so easy. At the very least you can re-own all your files with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```

The permissions mask 755/644 isn't terrible but some things like ~/.ssh need more restrictive permissions in order to work. If you're not willing or able to compare against a proper setup, it may simply be easier to create a new user and copy your documents over.

Comment: I tried to make a new user and delete the old one but I got error message. So I did "ls -l" and this what came up, please tell me what you think.

http://i.imgur.com/B342tRy.png

Comment: That actually looks okay.